# Unhandled rejection Error: no such file or directory, resultsCapturer.js:.will-be-removed-after-cucumber-runs.tmp'

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, cucumber

I am trying to automate an Angular 4 application. When I run "protractor config.js"

CASE 1: When I have format option in my config.ts file to something like this:

```
format: ['json:../reporting/results.json']
```

I get an error message:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\MyWorkspace\ProtractorProjects\protractor-cucumber-sample\test\config\MyWorkspace\ProtractorProjects\protractor-cucumber-sample\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\resultsCapturer.js:.will-be-removed-after-cucumber-runs.tmp'
at Error (native)

Process finished with exit code 100
Empty test suite.
```

All I understand is that it is unable to reach **"resultsCapturer.js"**. As **config.js** file's relative path is getting added and I am not sure how to fix this.

CASE 2: When I change format option to:

```
format: ['pretty']
```

I get an error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module 'C:\MyWorkspace\protractor-cucumber-sample\test\config\pretty'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
```

Checked [this doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules) but could not help me to fix the issue

Below are my project details:

node version: **v6.10.3**

protractor version: **5.1.2**

**config.ts:**

```
import { Config } from 'protractor';

export let config: Config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ["../features/*.feature"],

framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework'),

baseUrl: "http://localhost:4200/",

cucumberOpts: {
    compiler: "ts:ts-node/register",
    strict: true,
    format: ['json:../reporting/results.json'],
    require: ['../steps/*.js'],
    tags: '@smoke'
 }
}
```

**package.json:**

```
{
 "name": "protractor-cucumber-sample",
 "version": "0.0.0",
 "private": true,
 "scripts": {
 "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
"dependencies": {
 "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.53",
 "body-parser": "~1.17.1",
 "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
 "debug": "~2.6.3",
 "express": "~4.15.2",
 "jade": "~1.11.0",
 "morgan": "~1.8.1",
 "serve-favicon": "~2.4.2"
 },
"devDependencies": {
 "@types/chai": "^4.0.3",
 "@types/cucumber": "^2.0.3",
 "@types/mkdirp": "^0.5.0",
 "chai": "^4.1.1",
 "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
 "cucumber": "^3.0.0",
 "cucumber-html-reporter": "^2.0.3",
 "jasmine": "^2.7.0",
 "jasminewd2": "^2.1.0",
 "protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.0.2",
 "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
 "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "typeRoots": [
   "./node_modules/@types/"
    ],
  "lib": ["es2015"],
  "strict": true
 },
 "compileOnSave": true,
 "exclude": [
  "node_modules/*",
  "**/*-aot.ts"
  ]
}
```

Please let me know If I need to produce additional info which helps you to address this issue.

Also please suggest if this is not the right forum to post this question or in case you know other forums where this question can be posted.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:** The reason you are getting the **No such file or directory error** is because your directory **reporting/results.json** does not exist. Cucumber does not create directories internally , you have to create the `reporting` directory. It would certainly work.

**Case 2:** By looking at your package.json you are using **cucumber 3.0**, cucumber has removed **pretty** format since the latest cucumber 3.0 release. Please check the official [cucumber changelog](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#master-unreleased) for details. You can no longer use it , better switch to other formatting options- [cucumber formats](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/cli.md#formats) or downgrade your cucumber version.

Comment: CASE 1: No such file or directory error message is for **resultsCapture.js** but not for **/reporting** directory. (And I have created **/reporting** directory in my project.)

CASE 2: I agree. I guess we got [new release](https://github.com/protractor-cucumber-framework/protractor-cucumber-framework/issues/95) for the same. @Ram Pasala

Comment: **CASE1:** If we notice the absolute path in the error message,

the absolute path of  **config.js** file is getting added i.e. `C:\MyWorkspace\ProtractorProjects\protractor-cucumber-sample\test\config`

then it adds absolute path of  **resultsCapturer.js.** i.e. `\MyWorkspace\ProtractorProjects\protractor-cucumber-sample\node_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\resultsCapturer.js`

Comment: Then I guess it is due to new version of `protractor-cucumber-framework`, I see that darrin is already helping you out!